# Wordpress: Proper way to replace the_content only for pages created by custom plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a plugin that needs to replace `the_content` of only two specific pages that it created upon activation.

Here is my code:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'emd_content');  

function emd_content() {
  if ( is_page('Member Directory') ) {
      include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/content-members.php'; 
    }
    elseif ( is_page('Contact Members') ) {
      include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/content-member-contact-form.php'; 
    }
    else {
        the_content();
    }
}
```

The code above gives me a `500 Internal Server Error` for pages other than `Member Directory` and `Contact Members`, which both work properly.

If I remove `else { the_content(); }`, then the `Member Directory` and `Contact Members` work correctly, but all other pages don't display anything where `the_content` should be displayed.

I also tried wrapping the `add_filter()` within `if(is_page('Member Directory') || is_page('Contact Members')) {  }`. `the_content` worked for other pages, but not for the two created by the plugin.

**What is a better/proper way to replace `the_content` for these two pages using my plugin?**

Comment: In a nutshell, a filter must always `return` a value - `the_content()` just `echo`s and is likely causing an infinite loop since it would call your filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add parameter to your function. After this, you can $content, the_content() instead. Example:

```
function emd_content($content) {
  if ( is_page('Member Directory') ) {
      $content = include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/content-members.php'; 
    }
    elseif ( is_page('Contact Members') ) {
      $content = include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/content-member-contact-form.php'; 
    }
    else {
      $content = $content;
    }
      return $content;
}
```